# Can't add a rightBarButtonItem to a UIViewController

Tags: xcode, xcode4, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationitem, rightbarbuttonitem

I have the next code:

```
- (id) initWith...{
  if (self == [super initWithNibName:@"EmptyViewController"
     bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]]){ 
     ...

    back_btn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" 
                                                style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered 
                                               target:self
                                               action:@selector(backParentViewController)];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = back_btn;
    update_btn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemRefresh
                                                               target:self action:@selector(refresh)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = update_btn;
    self.title = [utils LabelFromKey:@"commons.nav-button.reports"];
        self.navigationItem.title = [utils LabelFromKey:@"commons.nav-button.reports"];
}
```

But the rightBarButton is not visible.

I try to move the code to the viewDidLoad, and to set the buttons to the navigationController.navigationItem but doesn't show the button

```
self.navigationController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = update_btn;
```

Any suggestions ¿?

Thank you

Comment: Do you navigation controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the delay, to make it works you must apply UIBarButtonItem the in the method viewDidAppear

Answer (score 1):

Eliminate the ivar `update_btn`. Start your allocation in `viewDidLoad` with

```
UIBarButtonItem *update_btn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] init...;
```

Assign the item with this statement:

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = update_btn;
[update_btn release];
```

Let me know if this works for you.